# access a variable in a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am 90% sure this doesn't work because i'm doing it the wrong way, but i can't figure out what is the "right way",I hope you can get my point :
I am trying to access an ipv4 of a certain interface,I have in my hosts file `interface_lan = enp4s0` because i need it in a role,so i thought i might just use it to have the IP address of that interface :

`"{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_{{interface_lan}']['ipv4.address']}}"`
with that command,he is looking for `"ansible_{{interface_lan}}"` but i want him to look for
`"ansible_"{{interface_lan}}""` and to consider `"{{interface_lan}}"` as a variable,not as a string.
I tried my best to explain,sorry if you did not understand you are free to enjoy the rest of your day without helping me, i have been ignoring this line for a few days now.
thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the name of the attribute an use it in the index. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    interface_lan: enp4s0
    ansible_enp4s0:
      ipv4:
        address: 10.1.0.10
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ansible_enp4s0: "{{ ansible_enp4s0 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][my_ifc]['ipv4']['address'] }}"
      vars:
        my_ifc: "{{ 'ansible_' ~ interface_lan }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 10.1.0.10
```

Note: `set_fact` is needed in the example to put the dictionary `ansible_enp4s0` into the `hostvars`.

---

The indirect addressing of variables without `hostvars` is possible with the lookup plugin [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables). For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_eth0: 10.1.0.10
    test_eth1: 10.1.0.11
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ lookup('vars', 'test_' ~ item ) }}"
      loop:
        - eth0
        - eth1
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'eth0: 10.1.0.10'
  msg: 'eth1: 10.1.0.11'
```